# How to change text "onmouseover" with variables?

Tags: javascript, html

I don't know why my code isn't working. I am trying to change  the text onmouseover with function with variables without Tag.

```
<script>
    function mouseOver(var h1,h2) {
        var str = h1;
        var res = str.valueOf();
        document.getElementById(h2).innerHTML = res; 
    }
</script>
<h2 id="demo" onmouseover="mouseOver(shalom,demo)">שלום</h2>
```

Comment: Are there any errors in the developer tools of your browser?

Comment: This code has nothing to do with C# or Visual Studio. I've edited the tags to show JavaScript instead.

Answer (score 0):

Change the code as below:

```
<script>
    function mouseOver(h1,h2) {
        var str = h1;
        var res = str.valueOf();
        document.getElementById(demo).innerHTML = res;
    }
</script>
```

Note: Instead of passing ID, you are passing the tag in "document.getElementById"

Comment: this is not working i am trying to this that the id in the veriables

Comment: What you are trying to say?

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to add `var` to the parameters of your function.

Also, you should put `'` around your values, otherwise javascript will look for variables with that name and won't find them.

```
<script>
    function mouseOver(h1, h2) {
        var str = h1;
        var res = str.valueOf();
        document.getElementById(h2).innerHTML = res;
    }
</script>
<h2 id="demo" onmouseover="mouseOver('shalom', 'demo')">שלום</h2>
```